# tmpfs does not overflow to swap

Tags: ubuntu, tmp, tmpfs

I've configured `tmp` in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 2
```

The problem is that now `/tmp` is limited to half of the machine's memory, and when it reaches that limit I'm getting "no space left on device" error.

I'd like to make it "unlimited", i.e. grow to the size of the disk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I get the impression you have a few misconceptions regarding `tmpfs`. You might find it useful to read the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/tmpfs.html) on the topic; I’ll attempt to clarify things for you here.

Your question’s title “`tmpfs` does not overflow to swap” doesn’t seem to reflect the actual contents of your question, but in any case `tmpfs` does use swap, although arguably it doesn’t overflow to swap. `tmpfs` is fundamentally a (virtual) memory-based file system; its contents live in memory only, but since they’re swappable the kernel can store them in swap instead of physical memory if necessary. Nevertheless `tmpfs` file systems can’t be larger than the total amount of virtual memory available, *i.e.* physical RAM and swap, as indicated *e.g.* by `free -h`.

By default `tmpfs` file systems have a maximum size equal to half the amount of physical memory available. You can increase this using the `size` parameter, but again it can’t ever be more than the available physical memory and swap (although that limit isn’t enforced at mount time). Once the file system reaches its maximum size (or rather, contains files occupying that much space), it reports that it’s run out of space, as you found out. `tmpfs` itself doesn’t support overflowing anywhere when it runs out of space.

If you need temporary storage space for large files, you should use `/var/tmp` rather than `/tmp`. You really don’t want a very large `tmpfs` file system, that’s a recipe for disaster when it fills up (the kernel’s usual ways of recovering memory don’t work in a `tmpfs`).

(If you have lots of RAM of course, a large `tmpfs` can work. I run a few systems with build `tmpfs` file systems sized at 75% of RAM, out of 32GiB, 64GiB or even more.)

Comment: Isn't there any mechanism for adding a secondary tmp? For example, having a main tmpfs for `/tmp`, and then another `/tmp2`, in a conventional disk, that might be used only if `/tmp` is full.

Comment: @jesjimher I’m not aware of anything like that.

Comment: @jesjimher you can set tmpfs size to larger than the actual RAM in your system and provide enough swap space to handle the usage as needed. If you want temporary setup only you can do something like as root `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile42 bs=1m count=8192 && chmod 600 /swapfile42 && mkswap /swapfile42 && swapon /swapfile42`. If some process now starts to write to tmpfs the system RAM is first used as much as possible but when you run out of RAM, the rest will be written to swap. For permanent setup, you can define swap in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [aufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs). It let's you "merge" two different mounts inside a single directory. So, in this case you could mount both a tmpfs volume somewhere and a conventional directory on disk, and then unify them using aufs as `/tmp`. You can even assign priorities, so tmpfs would be used first, and disk would only be used when tmpfs runs out of space.

It's not a perfect solution, though, because aufs works as a per file basis. So, if some process creates a file that starts growing slowly beyond tmpfs size, it won't "switch" volumes when tmpfs is full. It'll just get out of space (or some generic I/O error, since technically there's still space left in `/tmp`). But in a lot of scenarios it might do the trick of having `/tmp` in memory, and just fall back to disk when it grows too much.