# How to extend tmpfs with physical volume?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, tmp, tmpfs

I'm using 2G of `tmpfs` for `/tmp` dir to increase performance for java unit-testing: they are performing IO operations intensively in `/tmp`.
Here is my tmp section from `/etc/fstab` file:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,noatime,size=2G,nodev,mode=1777,noexec,nosuid,rootcontext=system_u:object_r:tmp_t 0 0
```

Almost always it's working fine, but sometimes I need more than 2G disk space in `/tmp`. It usually happens when some application downloading updates. In this case performance is not critical for me, so I'd like to write it to physical volume or loopback file.

Is it possible to use `tmpfs` if `/tmp` dir size is less than 2G and extend it with other file system when required?

Comment: Could the program not perform the download in another path?

Comment: @Kusalananda no, I can't control this programs

Comment: If the program downloads into a directory under `/tmp`, symlink it to somewhere else?

Comment: How much physical RAM do you have?

Comment: Related: [tmpfs does not overflow to swap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365291/86440).

Comment: @StephenKitt I have 8G RAM

Comment: Can you change the paths used by the *unit tests* for their temporary files? (Probably using `java.io.tmpdir`...) That way you could have `/tmp` as a regular filesystem, big enough for the applications downloading updates, and a tmpfs just for your unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to change *tmpfs* size, you can remount it on-line with new size:

```
mount -o remount,size=<new size> /tmp
```

Also, have a sufficiently large swap on your system. When available free RAM is low, memory (including tmpfs) will be paged to swap.

Swap won't be slowing your system, kernel swaps the least used and cached first and the balance can be adjusted with `vm.swappiness` parameter. For a good explanation for `vm.swappiness`, see [*Why is swappiness set to 60 by default?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88693/why-is-swappiness-set-to-60-by-default). If the system starts to slow due active pages being swapped, the cause is not swap; the reason is that your system is running out of RAM.

You can increase total swap space by creating a swap file (note: you can't place a swap file on [*btrfs*](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_swap_files.3F) file system). Create and allocate a new file with `dd` and set it up as swap area with `mkswap`. Make sure the swap file is not world readable, you don't want to leak your memory contents.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=<swap file> bs=1M count=<size>
chmod 600 <swap file>
mkswap <swap file>
```

And to enable it:

```
swapon <swap file>
```

You can also add the swap file to *fstab* to make it available automatically.

Comment: Thanks for anwer, but it doesn't satisfy me, because it makes all other applications slow. I want to control `tmpfs` size that used by `/tmp`

Comment: From my long experience with Linux systems, swap unfortunatelly slow down systems in most use cases.